# RecyclerView show no folding cells?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

i used ramotion Folding cells on a normal layout it worked fine, but now i am trying to create a recycler view with ramotion FOLDING CELLS, but the recycler view show nothing at all, how to solve this problem and make the cards appear?

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

activity_main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:name="com.example.foldingcell.MyFragment"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

MyFragment (that host the recycler view)

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;

public MyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    recyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter();

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
}
}
```

freagment_my

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyFragment">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

row (for recycler view)

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row
            , parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.tv1.setText("Test 1");
    holder.tv2.setText("Test 2");

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

   public final FoldingCell fc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.folding_cell);
   public TextView tv1;
   public TextView tv2;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tv1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_tv1);
        tv2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_tv2);

        fc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        fc.toggle(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is your fragment showing up in your activity? Make sure your Row file is there properly.

Comment: your getItemCount() returns 0?

Comment: because getItemCount()  return 0;

Comment: You should never set return 0 in getItemCount() if you do so it will never create views for you even if you have data

Comment: oh i forgot it, as i wasn't getting data from a list, thank you guys.